# Find AD-user by Email

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get users from active directory, who have a certain email address.

I've got a CSV-File, which contains the emails.

```
$data = import-csv -path .\are.csv -delimiter +
foreach($i in $data) 
{
    get-aduser -filter {UserPrincipalName -like '$i.email'} 
}
```

My problem is, that I don't get any output. No error, no data. When I replace `$i.email` with one of the email addresses, I get the right user information for the one user. So hard coding works.

When I do:

```
foreach($i in $data)
{
   $i.email
}
```

I get a list of all the emails.

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is within *single quotes* thus **doesn't get populated**. You have to three options to fix that:

Use *double quotes with a sub expression* `$()`:

```
UserPrincipalName -like "$($i.email)"
```

Just *omit* the quotes:

```
UserPrincipalName -like $i.email
```

And finally you could use a *format string* (even with single quotes):

```
UserPrincipalName -like ('{0}' -f $i.email)
```

---

Here is an example to demonstrate what actual value gets passed using the `Write-Host` cmdlet:

```
$data = 
@'
email, id
myname@web.de, 1
'@ | convertfrom-csv

foreach($i in $data) 
{
    Write-Host '$i.email'  # This is your current approach
    Write-Host "$($i.email)"
    Write-Host $i.email
    Write-Host ('{0}' -f $i.email)
}
```

**Output:**

```
$i.email # This is the output of your current approach
myname@web.de
myname@web.de
myname@web.de
```

Comment: When I put them in double quotes - nothing changes. Still no output. When I omit them, I get an error message: "Property "email" was not found in Object of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject".

Comment: Did you also put it into a sub expression? All of the three provided examples should work.

Comment: What do you mean by sub expression? I just replaced the -filter argument with the given examples.